# ag-grid tabToNextCell Implementation

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm having trouble using `tabToNextCell` with ag-grid in Angular. I'm wanting to add a new row when someone tabs to the end of the table. I am set up as follows:

```html
<ag-grid-angular
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [rowData]="bidders$ | async"
  [tabToNextCell]="onTab"
  [stopEditingWhenCellsLoseFocus]="true"
  class="ag-theme-alpine"
  domLayout='autoHeight'
  style="width: 100%;"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

And in my component, `onTab` and `addBidder` look like this:

```js
  onTab({nextCellPosition, previousCellPosition}: TabToNextCellParams): CellPosition {
    if(!nextCellPosition) {
      this.addBidder()
      return previousCellPosition;
    }
    return nextCellPosition;
  }

  addBidder() {
    this.biddersService.addBidder();
  }
```

However, when I tab to the end and trigger the call to `this.addBidder()`, `this` is undefined and I get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addBidder')
```

If I put in a breakpoint where it calls `this.addBidder()`, and inspect things, `this` is undefined at that point. So, I feel like there's some sort of trick to how the `onTab` function should be constructed.

Also, I tried passing the `addBidder()` method to the `onTab()` method in the `[tabToNextCell]` assignment and that doesn't work either:

Template:

```html
<ag-grid-angular
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [rowData]="bidders$ | async"
  [tabToNextCell]="onTab(addBidder)"
  [stopEditingWhenCellsLoseFocus]="true"
  class="ag-theme-alpine"
  domLayout='autoHeight'
  style="width: 100%;"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

And in the component, I changed onTab to the following:

```js
  onTab(func: any) {
    return ({nextCellPosition, previousCellPosition}: TabToNextCellParams): CellPosition => {
      if (!nextCellPosition) {
        func();
        return previousCellPosition;
      }
      return nextCellPosition;
    };
  }
```

However, `this` is undefined when calling `this.biddersService.addBidder()` inside of the `addBidder()` method within the component.

Comment: I read differently. the error message. do you have addBidder() method? it's addBidder that is not defined , not this

Comment: Sorry @Vega ... I didn't put the addBidder method in the original example. I added that in as well as another example of troubleshooting this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK...after struggling with this for too long, I realized I could make onTab an arrow function and that would handle the `this` problem:

```js
  onTab = ({nextCellPosition, previousCellPosition}: TabToNextCellParams): CellPosition => {
    if (!nextCellPosition) {
      this.addBidder();
      return previousCellPosition;
    }
    return nextCellPosition;
  };
```

Defining `OnTab` as above works!

Comment: You can also set the 'this' in context while configuring the grid options. You can access it via params.